# Denodo HTTP Client given date in request

Tags: denodo

I need to query HTTP/JSON datasource with parameters like this:

`/values?Name=Foobar&Start=2024-01-16&End=2024-01-17` (the previous and the current days)

so I create a Base view with relative URL like this:

`/values?Name=Foobar&Start=@start&End=@end`

and then I try to use functions for `START` and `END` variables, e.g:

START: `FORMATDATE('yyyy-MM-dd', ADDDAY(now(), -1))` (Is this correct for `yesturday`??)

END: `FORMATDATE('yyyy-MM-dd', now())`

but denodo uses formulas as a plaintext:

```
Unable to obtain the data structure:
com.denodo.util.exceptions.InternalErrorException:
Error retrieving data from '.../values?Name=Foobar&End=FORMATDATE('yyyy-MM-dd',%20now())'.
HTTP error code: 404.
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question [was answered at Denodo Community website](https://community.denodo.com/answers/question/details?questionId=906Du00000001dGIAQ) with Denodo team

> Hi,
>
> Generally the values in interpolation variables are passed as strings.
> If I need to pass dynamic values in the interpolation variables, I
> would follow the below steps:
>
> 1. I would create a new HTTP/JSON datasource named `ds_sample` with the base URL as mentioned below:
>
>    ```
>     <BASE_URL>/values?Start=@start&End=@end
>    ```
> 2. After saving the data source, I would create a base view, `bv_sample` over the `ds_sample` source.
> 3. Then, I would create a new view named `dates` with two fields `Start` and `End` with the field expression
>    `formatdate('yyyy-MM-dd', addday(now(), -1))` for `Start` and
>    `formatdate('yyyy-MM-dd', now())` for `End` fields.
> 4. I would create a [Join view](https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/8.0/en/vdp/administration/creating_derived_views/creating_join_views/creating_join_views) for the two base views `dates` and `bv_sample` and I would join the fields `dates.start`, `dates.end` and
>    `bv_sample.start`, `bv_sample.end` respectively.
> 5. Finally, on executing the join view the results of the query matching the given conditions will be retrieved.
>
> Hope this helps!

UPD

For beginners, the least obvious item may be the one about "create a new view named `dates`", I still don't know the correct way, too=) So you can create any type of View in the UI, open it's VQL editor and put this code there:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dates FOLDER = '/general'
 LAYOUT (bv_sample = [20, 20, 200, 205])
 AS SELECT
  formatdate('yyyy-MM-dd', addday(now(), -1)) AS "Yesterday",
  formatdate('yyyy-MM-dd', addday(now(), -1)) AS "Start",
  formatdate('yyyy-MM-dd', now()) AS "Today",
  formatdate('yyyy-MM-dd', now()) AS "End"
 CONTEXT ('formatted' = 'yes');
```